# Spring Security 5 - How to SSO from id_token (Google one-tap)

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-openid, google-identity

I'm working on an application with Spring Boot 5 and OIDC. I've configured OIDC with Google and it works fine. I'm redirected to login at Google and then it redirects me to the app creating a new session. Now I'm trying to use [Google One-Tap](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web). It works fine as well. When user clicks on the one-tap's modal to continue with his Google identity I receive a POST with the id_token. What I want to do is to create a Spring session from this POST as it is created when user is logged by OIDC.

I think the right way is to create a `Filter` extending `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`. I've found some references [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-openid-connect-legacy) and [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/web/OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.java) but I don't have the `access_token` when receiving the one-tap POST:

```java
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        ...
        OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauth2Authentication = new OAuth2AuthenticationToken(
            authenticationResult.getPrincipal(),
            authenticationResult.getAuthorities(),
            authenticationResult.getClientRegistration().getRegistrationId());
        oauth2Authentication.setDetails(authenticationDetails);

        OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient = new OAuth2AuthorizedClient(
            authenticationResult.getClientRegistration(),
            oauth2Authentication.getName(),
            authenticationResult.getAccessToken(),
            authenticationResult.getRefreshToken());

        this.authorizedClientRepository.saveAuthorizedClient(authorizedClient, oauth2Authentication, request, response);

        return oauth2Authentication;
}
```

Has anyone tried to do it before ?

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found a solution. I've shared the code [here](https://github.com/Identicum/spring-sso-filter/blob/master/src/main/java/com/identicum/config/OidcSsoFilter.java). Hope it helps to anyone dealing with the same issue.